# SharePoint 2013 Custom result page URL for search queries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to redirect the search queries to a search center url. I've created the search center and I use the Search Settings to set a result page url (my search center results.aspx).

I've tried setting the custom page for site collection and leave the site setting on "Use the same results page as my parent". I've also tried setting the custom page url directly in the site setting. But still the search results is shown on the site's "osssearchresults.aspx" page.
Am I forgetting something? It's like sharepoint is ignoring those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the actual search box web part settings. There is a properties for Search box where you can choose to use the default or you can send queries to a custom results page URL.

See if that is where the issue is.

Try this link for further information > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-box-web-part